# Escaping spaces in ruby

Tags: ruby, powershell, chef-infra

When I execute the following script block, I get an error:

```
powershell_script 'uninstall_something' do
   code 'wmic /failfast:on product where "name like 'Something Enterprise(64-bit)'" call uninstall /nointeractive'
   guard_interpreter :powershell_script
end

FATAL: SyntaxError: .\check.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting keyword_end
...roduct where "name like 'Something Enterprise(64-bit)'" call un...
                                     ^
.\check.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_end
...ike 'Something Enterprise(64-bit)'" call uninstall /nointeracti...
                                     ^
```

I have tried escaping the spaces but I still get the error. If I execute the same PowerShell command in PowerShell, I don't get any error.
What am I missing?

Comment: You have to escape your interior single quotes.  Your string right now is `code 'wmic /failfast:on product where "name like '` and everything after that is a syntax error.

Comment: @Joe If I do that, the script succeeds without any errors but it fails to do what its supposed to do, i.e, uninstall Something Enterprise.

`code 'wmic /failfast:on product where "name like \'Something Enterprise(64-bit)\'" call uninstall /nointeractive'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%q[...]` if both other quotes are already in use:

```
code %q[wmic /failfast:on product where "name like 'Something Enterprise(64-bit)'" call uninstall /nointeractive]
```

Comment: If I do that, the script succeeds without any errors but it fails to do what its supposed to do, i.e, uninstall Something Enterprise

Comment: That's a problem, I'm sure, but it's also another question. Stack Overflow tries to keep things focused on one issue at a time. It helps crowd out these questions with lots of other confusion.